# While storing 0.0 in a datatable it gets stored as 0 only

Tags: c#, asp.net

Have a query hope someone can help.

I have a datatable dt1 which has three columns a,b,c (of datatype string, float, float resp).
Then I have a datatable dt2 which is a clone of dt1, and the values of dt1 are merged into dt2.

Now the issue is for a particular condition:

when the first row is this:

```
dt1.Rows.Add("xyz", 0.0, 0.0);
```

But I can see the value is taken as xyz,0,0 in the datatable.
This I am merging to dt2 as

```
if (dt2 == null)

     {
         dt2 = dt1.Clone();
     }

     dt2.Merge(dt1, true);
```

Now when I merge for the second time with say some vale in dt1 as ("mnp",4.5,8.9) I get an error at `dt2.Merge(dt1, true);`

> Error: .b and .b have
>   conflicting properties: DataType
>   property mismatch.

where b is the column name.

Have defined the table dt1 as:

```
DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();

   dt1.Columns.Add("a", typeof(string));

   dt1.Columns.Add("b", typeof(float));

   dt1.Columns.Add("c", typeof(float));`
```

Comment: I would seem dt2 is defined differently: please post its definition.

Comment: dt2 is clone of dt1 as I have mentioned. and defined as DataTable dt2 = null;

Hope this is what you tring to look for.

Comment: Is this reproducible without a database? If so, can you provide a mcve? https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve I can't see clearly where the database is involved from the extracted snippets.

Answer (score 1):

Avi, the following Code runs with no errors in VS 2008 with Target Frameworks 2.0, 3.0 and 3.5:

```
using System.Data;

namespace DtCheck
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();

            dt1.Columns.Add("a", typeof(string));
            dt1.Columns.Add("b", typeof(float));
            dt1.Columns.Add("c", typeof(float));

            dt1.Rows.Add("xyz", 0.0, 0.0);

            DataTable dt2;

            dt2 = dt1.Clone();

            dt2.Merge(dt1, true);

            dt1.Rows.Add("mnp", 4.5, 8.9);

            dt2.Merge(dt1, true);
        }
    }
}
```

Can you try my program on your machine? What's the result? If it works, too, something in your program must be different.

Maybe you reassign dt2 to something else before the second merge? Or is it already set at the "if (dt2 == null)", so that the Clone() does not execute?

By the way: the first Clone/Merge can be reduced to dt2 = dt1.Copy()

Answer (score 0):

How about if you postfix them with "f"??

`("mnp",4.5f,8.9f)`

I think maybe they're being interpreted by the compiler as double and not float.

Comment: I tried defining double for the columns of dt1 as  
dt1.Columns.Add("b", typeof(double)); 
It's still giving same error.

Comment: I tried defining double for the columns of dt1 as dt1.Columns.Add
("b", typeof(double)); It's still giving same error. And also I 
can't write the way u have written as the value of data in dt1 is 
being polulated from a sql query. except when the sql returns null
 value I manually add a row to the datatable dt1 as 
dt1.Rows.Add("xyz", 0.0, 0.0); When the sql value is not null the 
values of dt1 is dt1 = GetDataTable(strSQL); Where GetDataTable is 
function which returns a datatable for the query strSQL.
 Hope there is some way.

Comment: maybe instead of 0.0 try (float)double.Epsilon, or just single.Epsilon?  This would be an extreme hack, but since double.Epsilon =  4.94065645841247e-324 and single.Epsilon = 1.4e-45, it should still recognize a minimal value.  Even if you store single.Epsilon instead of 0.0, the merge values should remain accurate since you're only accounting for tenths.

Comment: @Jim : didn't get u exactly .. But do mean some thing like this dt1.Columns.Add ("b", typeof((float)double));